# Multi-Column Value Look Up

Tags: r

I need help with character string processing. I'm taking contracts from a broker statement, and I want to be able to assign high level categories to each contract based on a specific value being contained in the string. For example, if I have the contract **MAY 16 SOYBEAN OIL**, I want to be able to categorize this as a *grain* and as then as *soybean oil*. Essentially, I want to create a sort of dictionary where I can feed in a column of contracts and then I can spit out two more columns after, a column that defines a sector and then the next column defines the futures contract type. So far I've tried `matrix$breakdown <- strsplit(matrix$contract, " ")` to create `c("MAY", "16", "SOYBEAN", "OIL")`, which gives me individual character strings to check values. My thought was to create a sort of dictionary since, besides the date, the contract characters generally won't change. For example, a function of some sort that checks to see if *SOYBEAN* and *OIL* is contained in the string and if it is then give me *grain* as the sector, and *soybean oil* as the futures contract type. And there may be a much easier way to do this. I don't care about the method, I just need a system that is robust. The reason I'm doing this is I want to be able automate a calculation that relies on categories. So after I set up the above (sector and futures contract) then I would tack on in new columns the contract size multiplier, etc, which is dependent on the contract type, such as *soybean oil*. Long winded I know...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you have a lookup table you can use `grep()` to see if values exist within a character string. This would result in not needed to split the string, for example: `if(grepl("SOYBEAN",x) & grepl("OIL",x)=T){x$cat <- "Grain"}` There is a better way to do this for a lookup table but splitting the string may not be the most efficient. Check out grepping is what I'm getting at.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!